# Regarding a conversation between Miss. Price, Miss. Crawford and Edmund in Mansfield Park by Jane Austen

Tags: jane-austen, mansfield-park

I am reading chapter 11 of Mansfield Park by Jane Austen. There is a conversation going on between Fanny, Edmund, and Mrs. Crawford. In the book the conversation is going on without explicitly mentioning who is the speaker. Since there are three speakers, I am unable to follow who is speaking the following sentences. If anyone could help me regarding who is speaking which sentence, it would be of great help.

> Edmund looked round at Mr. Rushworth too, but had nothing to say.
>
> "Your father's return will be a very interesting event."
>
> "It will, indeed, after such an absence; an absence not only long, but
>   including so many dangers."
>
> "It will be the forerunner also of other interesting events: your
>   sister's marriage, and your taking orders."
>
> "Yes."
>
> "Don't be affronted," said she, laughing, "but it does put me in mind
>   of some of the old heathen heroes, who, after performing great
>   exploits in a foreign land, offered sacrifices to the gods on their
>   safe return."
>
> "There is no sacrifice in the case," replied Edmund, with a serious
>   smile, and glancing at the pianoforte again; "it is entirely her own
>   doing."
>
> "Oh yes I know it is. I was merely joking. She has done no more than
>   what every young woman would do; and I have no doubt of her being
>   extremely happy. My other sacrifice, of course, you do not
>   understand."
>
> "My taking orders, I assure you, is quite as voluntary as Maria's
>   marrying." "It is fortunate that your inclination and your father's
>   convenience should accord so well. There is a very good living kept
>   for you, I understand, hereabouts."
>
> "Which you suppose has biassed me?"
>
> "But that I am sure it has not," cried Fanny.
>
> "Thank you for your good word, Fanny, but it is more than I would
>   affirm myself. On the contrary, the knowing that there was such a
>   provision for me probably did bias me. Nor can I think it wrong that
>   it should. There was no natural disinclination to be overcome, and I
>   see no reason why a man should make a worse clergyman for knowing that
>   he will have a competence early in life. I was in safe hands. I hope I
>   should not have been influenced myself in a wrong way, and I am sure
>   my father was too conscientious to have allowed it. I have no doubt
>   that I was biased, but I think it was blamelessly."
>
> "It is the same sort of thing," said Fanny, after a short pause, "as
>   for the son of an admiral to go into the navy, or the son of a general
>   to be in the army, and nobody sees anything wrong in that. Nobody
>   wonders that they should prefer the line where their friends can serve
>   them best, or suspects them to be less in earnest in it than they
>   appear."
>
> "No, my dear Miss Price, and for reasons good. The profession, either
>   navy or army, is its own justification. It has everything in its
>   favour: heroism, danger, bustle, fashion. Soldiers and sailors are
>   always acceptable in society. Nobody can wonder that men are soldiers
>   and sailors."
>
> "But the motives of a man who takes orders with the certainty of
>   preferment may be fairly suspected, you think?" said Edmund. "To be
>   justified in your eyes, he must do it in the most complete uncertainty
>   of any provision."
>
> "What! take orders without a living! No; that is madness indeed;
>   absolute madness."
>
> "Shall I ask you how the church is to be filled, if a man is neither
>   to take orders with a living nor without? No; for you certainly would
>   not know what to say. But I must beg some advantage to the clergyman
>   from your own argument. As he cannot be influenced by those feelings
>   which you rank highly as temptation and reward to the soldier and
>   sailor in their choice of a profession, as heroism, and noise, and
>   fashion, are all against him, he ought to be less liable to the
>   suspicion of wanting sincerity or good intentions in the choice of
>   his."
>
> "Oh! no doubt he is very sincere in preferring an income ready made,
>   to the trouble of working for one; and has the best intentions of
>   doing nothing all the rest of his days but eat, drink, and grow fat.
>   It is indolence, Mr. Bertram, indeed. Indolence and love of ease; a
>   want of all laudable ambition, of taste for good company, or of
>   inclination to take the trouble of being agreeable, which make men
>   clergymen. A clergyman has nothing to do but be slovenly and
>   selfish—read the newspaper, watch the weather, and quarrel with his
>   wife. His curate does all the work, and the business of his own life
>   is to dine."
>
> "There are such clergymen, no doubt, but I think they are not so
>   common as to justify Miss Crawford in esteeming it their general
>   character. I suspect that in this comprehensive and (may I say)
>   commonplace censure, you are not judging from yourself, but from
>   prejudiced persons, whose opinions you have been in the habit of
>   hearing. It is impossible that your own observation can have given you
>   much knowledge of the clergy. You can have been personally acquainted
>   with very few of a set of men you condemn so conclusively. You are
>   speaking what you have been told at your uncle's table."
>
> "I speak what appears to me the general opinion; and where an opinion
>   is general, it is usually correct. Though I have not seen much of the
>   domestic lives of clergymen, it is seen by too many to leave any
>   deficiency of information."
>
> "Where any one body of educated men, of whatever denomination, are
>   condemned indiscriminately, there must be a deficiency of information,
>   or (smiling) of something else. Your uncle, and his brother admirals,
>   perhaps knew little of clergymen beyond the chaplains whom, good or
>   bad, they were always wishing away."
>
> "Poor William! He has met with great kindness from the chaplain of the
>   Antwerp," was a tender apostrophe of Fanny's, very much to the purpose
>   of her own feelings if not of the conversation.
>
> "I have been so little addicted to take my opinions from my uncle,"
>   said Miss Crawford, "that I can hardly suppose—and since you push me
>   so hard, I must observe, that I am not entirely without the means of
>   seeing what clergymen are, being at this present time the guest of my
>   own brother, Dr. Grant. And though Dr. Grant is most kind and obliging
>   to me, and though he is really a gentleman, and, I dare say, a good
>   scholar and clever, and often preaches good sermons, and is very
>   respectable, I see him to be an indolent, selfish bon vivant, who must
>   have his palate consulted in everything; who will not stir a finger
>   for the convenience of any one; and who, moreover, if the cook makes a
>   blunder, is out of humour with his excellent wife. To own the truth,
>   Henry and I were partly driven out this very evening by a
>   disappointment about a green goose, which he could not get the better
>   of. My poor sister was forced to stay and bear it."
>
> "I do not wonder at your disapprobation, upon my word. It is a great
>   defect of temper, made worse by a very faulty habit of
>   self-indulgence; and to see your sister suffering from it must be
>   exceedingly painful to such feelings as yours. Fanny, it goes against
>   us. We cannot attempt to defend Dr. Grant."
>
> "No," replied Fanny, "but we need not give up his profession for all
>   that; because, whatever profession Dr. Grant had chosen, he would have
>   taken a—not a good temper into it; and as he must, either in the navy
>   or army, have had a great many more people under his command than he
>   has now, I think more would have been made unhappy by him as a sailor
>   or soldier than as a clergyman. Besides, I cannot but suppose that
>   whatever there may be to wish otherwise in Dr. Grant would have been
>   in a greater danger of becoming worse in a more active and worldly
>   profession, where he would have had less time and obligation—where he
>   might have escaped that knowledge of himself, the frequency, at least,
>   of that knowledge which it is impossible he should escape as he is
>   now. A man—a sensible man like Dr. Grant, cannot be in the habit of
>   teaching others their duty every week, cannot go to church twice every
>   Sunday, and preach such very good sermons in so good a manner as he
>   does, without being the better for it himself. It must make him think;
>   and I have no doubt that he oftener endeavours to restrain himself
>   than he would if he had been anything but a clergyman."
>
> "We cannot prove to the contrary, to be sure; but I wish you a better
>   fate, Miss Price, than to be the wife of a man whose amiableness
>   depends upon his own sermons; for though he may preach himself into a
>   good-humour every Sunday, it will be bad enough to have him
>   quarrelling about green geese from Monday morning till Saturday
>   night."
>
> "I think the man who could often quarrel with Fanny," said Edmund
>   affectionately, "must be beyond the reach of any sermons." Fanny
>   turned farther into the window; and Miss Crawford had only time to
>   say, in a pleasant manner, "I fancy Miss Price has been more used to
>   deserve praise than to hear it"; when, being earnestly invited by the
>   Miss Bertrams to join in a glee, she tripped off to the instrument,
>   leaving Edmund looking after her in an ecstasy of admiration of all
>   her many virtues, from her obliging manners down to her light and
>   graceful tread.

Answer (score 3):

Every contribution from Fanny is attributed directly in the text.

> "It is the same sort of thing," said Fanny

...

> "Poor William! He has met with great kindness from the chaplain of the
>   Antwerp," was a tender apostrophe of Fanny's,

The main body of the conversation alternates between Edmund and Miss Crawford.

There is one point at which it gets a little confusing when Edmund is speaking in response to Miss crawford but referring to her in the third person:

> There are such clergymen, no doubt, but I think they are not so common as to justify Miss Crawford in esteeming it their general character.

but I think what we are to understand here is that he is keeping Fanny involved in the conversation, as a gentleman he would be mindful of the social graces, before returning to addressing Miss Crawford directly in the second person:

> I suspect that in this comprehensive and (may I say) commonplace censure, you are not judging from yourself, but from prejudiced persons, whose opinions you have been in the habit of hearing.

In his next reply Edmund makes reference to:

> Your uncle, and his brother admirals

Which squarely puts Mary, niece of 'the Admiral', as the originator of the arguments he is responding to.

The other textual clue is that Edmund always addresses Fanny by her first name, while Miss Crawford addresses her as 'Miss Price'.